# How to find translation fields for specific product in odoo 13

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-13

I'm trying to update product name translation using jsonRPC , i tried to watch the post request from chrome's network section i found that the requests arguments are :

```
params: {args: [[576104], {value: "Nilson Cadre Touran 01 Module Encastré."}], model: "ir.translation", method : "write"}
```

576104 here is the translation record ID but I can't find which ID is mapped to my product.template, name field! there's no reference to product id or something

where is the mapping part done?

PS: I'm on odoo 13 and my goal is to translate products names by coding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can search field translations of known records (in your example a product template) with 3 known data points: model name, record id and field name.

So as an example how to find translations for `product.template`s field `name` for record ID `4711` you can use following search domain:

```py
[('name', '=', 'product.template,name'), ('res_id', '=', 4711)]
```

That's a straight forward example, but usually you would like to do that programmatically by using those 3 mentioned data points as variables.

Keep the following situations in mind:

1. You find nothing --> means there is no translation yet, so you have to create one instead of updating a found one
2. You find more than one translation --> there is no language filter in the above domain filter, so when using more than one language besides English, you get all of the translations